# '92 Toyota Corolla with a oil leak

Tags: toyota, oil, leak

My 1992 Corolla is leaking oil when driving then pools while parked. Already checked the oil pan and no leak. Where else could it be coming from?

Comment: Perhaps the oil pump? Can you tell from where abouts in the engine it is dripping from (eg: front left side)

Answer (score 2):

One popular possibility is oil leaking past the rear main seal when running, accumulating in the transmission's bellhousing, and then draining from there when parked. Happens a lot when rear mains start to leak.

Oil around the rear of the oil pan, on the bottom of the transmission are all good signs of this.

[image: Rear main leak]

Answer (score 0):

Front main seal is a likely culprit also, where the majority of it is pooling when you park can tell a lot.